# Word/phrase to indicate time occupation

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, time

If someone has a tight schedule or is a little strange, for the sake of politeness, I want to say him that I am not in a rush and you can take whatever time you need to answer me.

Could you please give me some advice? Some phrases or words maybe.

Thanks

Comment: ...send me a reply to my email **at your earliest convenience**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At your earliest convenience [means](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-your-earliest-convenience):

> (formal) as soon as possible

and as in [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+earliest+convenience)

> A suitable or agreeable time

**E.g.** *Please let me know at your earliest convenience whether you can help me.*

And some writing tips on "[At Whose Earliest Convenience?](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/at-whose-earliest-convenience/)"

Comment: +1 for highlighting the formal sense- "as soon as possible".

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of :

> I am not [in a hurry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_a_hurry), you can reply **[as soon as possible](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_soon_as_possible)**. (ASAP)

Comment: This is an unusual use of A.S.A.P., which as far as I know, is usually used to indicate that you 'are' in a hurry but can't control the circumstances causing the delay. This may seem a little passive-aggressive as a result, despite the literal definitions and good intentions.

Comment: @Tonepoet I know but this may only is a meaning based on usage? The wiki def doesn't notice this hurry : *"As soon as is possible; at one's earliest convenience; at the earliest possible time."* And Eilia define her answer by using it as synonym.

Comment: If using A.S.A.P on its own, the soonest/earliest possible time would be the first moment that's available to you and none later. That's definitely a rush. It's the rest of the sentence that causes ambiguity. I think 'whenever possible' or 'as soon as you want' are probably better word choices. I'd also use 'may' instead of 'can' here.

Comment: @Tonepoet *possible* means possible for **him** to reply. I do not need to be available to receive an email. The sentence is basically stating : *"When you think it is possible, do it"*

Answer (score 1):

Just say politely something like "I don't need this right away, but I would appreciate it whenever you can get to it," or some such. There is no particular set phrase. Just explain the situation as clearly and politely as possible.